# How can I add support for a new file system type to an existing kernel?

Tags: filesystems, kernel-modules, arm

I have an ARM device running an OpenEmbedded-based kernel. A new requirement  is going to involve mounting an ISO 9660 file system, but that file system is not currently listed in /etc/filesystems. I know I could enable support for ISO 9660 in the kernel config, but I'm wondering if there is a way to push a module via software update that would add support for the new file system?

Comment: Isn't `mount -o loop` useful ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
# modprobe isofs
```

Whether or not you can get the module from a package depends on the distribution you're using.